# How to call data and view it on the footer?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

This is the function that I am using in my controller

```
    public function homeList()
{
    //Get all the franchises
    $franchises = Franchise::all();

    //Load the view and pass the franchises
            return View::make('frontend.layouts.footer')->with('franchises', $franchises);
    }
```

and I keep getting this error. I don't know how to pass it or what to put on the routes.php file

[image]

Comment: pleae post you relavent view code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do `@include('frontend.layouts.footer')->with('franchises', Franchise::all())`.

**Update:**

To avoid the model in the view, you should use a view composer, as it was stated in a previous answer.

```
View::composer('frontend.layouts.footer', function($view)
{
    $view->with('franchises', Franchise::all());
});
```

Now you have `$franchises` available in the view. This code you can place in `routes.php` or you can create a `composers.php` and autoload it.

Comment: Never do things like `Franchise::all()` in your views! They are not supposed to know that much about your business logic.